# Comma placement in "Another, just as important, aspect"

Tags: commas

Is the comma placement correct in

> Another, just as important, aspect is. . . .

or should they rather be omitted?

Comment: That comma is just a short cut for saying *and* instead: “Another and just as important aspect is that. . . .”

Comment: "Another **equally important** aspect" would express it just as clearly and without any commas. Bad for word count, though.

Answer (score 1):

The **word order** is incorrect. Though there is a lot of freedom in what may be included in parenthetheses, there is not *total* freedom.

One can't make up compound adjectives / adjectivals and hope they are acceptable pre-modifiers of a noun group just because they obviously make sense.

> *A just-as-important consideration is ...

Here, we need

> Another aspect, just as important, is ...

This may be considered to be formed by whiz-deletion from

> Another aspect, which is just as important, is ...

and perhaps it's valid to say that

> (*) Another(,) which is just as important(,) aspect, is ...

is obviously not acceptable.

Comment: Thank goodness *an equally important aspect* carries no hyphen.

Comment: Yes - * _Another, said by many to be less important important, aspect is ..._ needs re-ordering, whilst _Another, very slightly less important, aspect is. . . ._ doesn't. OK, I'm struggling to find an authority to pronounce here, but "a just as good / important aspect / reason" show no Ngram returns.